# 2D Runtime animation with different textures

Tags: unity, 2d, animation, sprites, skeletal-animation

We have a bunch of characters in our game. Although they look the same mainly, they do have differences. We are downloading the textures on runtime, generating an atlas that decreases the draw call, and creating sprites out of this atlas. During this process, Sprite Renderer creates the meshes automatically.

I also imported PSD files of the base characters and created the bones and animation on them. What I would like to achieve is to apply the bone to the sprite that I generated from the textures that I downloaded.

Some problems that I encounter:

- When I try directly changing the sprite on the PSB file to a
  downloaded and dynamically created sprite, I receive a mismatch on
  Bindposes.
- If I would like to create the bones and Bindposes dynamically, should
  use the SkinnedMeshRenderer as the example here
  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bindposes.html note
  that I am doing this for 2D. If not, can I override the meshes on the
  SpriteRendeder using sprite override
  (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.OverrideGeometry.html)?
  The problem here, I can't access the meshes of the sprite renderer as
  in SkinnedMeshRenderer so couldn't figure out how to assign bone
  weights.

Comment: How exactly are you downloading the textures? Are you using asset packs? Or are you downloading the raw .psd files?

Comment: I am downloading basically a png file which is an atlas and unpacking it to create Sprites.

Comment: Is this a case you can handle with the built-in [Sprite Swapping animation features](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.animation@6.0/manual/SpriteSwapIntro.html)?

Comment: I will check again however when I set up a template to try, I faced Transforms does not equal to Bindposes warning and the animation does not work.